window.opener is null - used to work until now
Summary: Somehow, window.opener of an opened tab stopped being populated, while not long ago (couple of months), it still worked.
I have a flow in my app in which the user is redirected to a Stripe payment screen in a new tab. Lets say my shop is hosted on https://shop.com
Because the checkout url is only generated after the user presses the "buy" button, I first open a new tab with const ref = window.open(). After that, I call ref.document?.write("Please wait...") to make sure the user sees something in the new tab.
When the promise resolves with the checkout url, I call ref.location = checkoutUrl, which redirects the tab to the Stripe checkout url on https://stripe.com.
When the checkout is done, Stripe redirects the page to another page inside my domain, namely https://shop.com/redirect. This redirect determines based on query params whether the payment succeeded or failed.
What I've been doing for ages, is call window?.opener?.postMessage('payment-success', '*'); on the opened tab to notify the original tab that the payment succeeded. After that, I call window.close() on the opened tab, to redirect the user back to the original page.
Now, quite recently, the window?.opener?.postMessage(...) call doesn't work anymore, because window?.opener is null. This has been working for ages, but now, it's not anymore. I looked up the last time I deployed my app, which was 177 days ago, and back then, it still worked.
Did something change regarding security policies? Both Chrome and Safari refuse to populate window?.opener. Does anybody have an idea what changed, and what I can do to fix this?

when you first ref.location = checkoutUrl ... is window.opener OK at that point?

Have you read window.opener documentation. The part that may be relevant is below In the following cases, the browser does not populate window.opener, but leaves it null ... do any of those apply, specifically the last

I think you'll have to work around. Can localstorage be used? Cuz  localstorage are synchronized across all tabs.

Is this problem because of the same-origin policy? If the checkout URL or any redirects go to a different website or subdomain, that could be why window.opener is null. You can check same-origin policy documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

I was running a rather old NestJS application. When I updated my NestJS version to the latest along with all its dependencies one of these packages was helmet. The upgrade of helmet had a breaking change that would turn on  Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy for all my API endpoints. I turned it back off and all was fine again.

(Remember that your answer is essentially a historical record of how to solve this specific problem, not a place for thanks or speculation)
